# Adjust text inside UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a `UIScrollView` in which I have 3 `UILabel` and 3 `UIButton`. I using following code to add my labels but it keeping top & bottom margin inside label.

```
    float height = 0.0f;        
    for (int i=0; i < answer_set.count; i++) {

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,height ,280,10 )];
        [label setText: [self.answer_set objectAtIndex:i]];
        [label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
        [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2941f green:0.4666f blue:0.9549f alpha:1.0f];
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        label.numberOfLines = 0;
        [label sizeToFit];
        label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0f] ;
        [self.percentage_ans_view addSubview:label];

        height += label.frame.size.height;
    }
```

In case of single line text its working correctly.
What should I do to remove these top/bottom spacing inside of label. ???

[image: label]

Comment: set the scroll background color and also check the frame of scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first YouShould get label Height base on text

```
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,height ,280,10 )];
    [label setText: [self.answer_set objectAtIndex:i]];
    [label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2941f green:0.4666f blue:0.9549f alpha:1.0f];
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0f] ;
    [self.percentage_ans_view addSubview:label];
    // get height base on label text and size
    CGFloat height=[self getStringHeightforLabel:label];
    //set fram after getting height  
    label.frame=CGRectMake(20,height,280,height);
    [label sizeToFit];
```

// call  this  to get heighjt

```
-(CGFloat)getStringHeightforLabel:(UILabel *)label
{
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width,9999);
CGSize stringSize= [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font
                              constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                  lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];
return stringSize.height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understood your question well, but if i did, you can use:

```
label.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, right, bittom, left);
```

to set the spacings inside the labels

Comment: `contentInset` property not found on object. I'm getting this.

Comment: yeah, sorry, only UITextView has contentInset property, maybe  using UITextView instead of UILabel?

Answer (score 0):

you need to place

```
    [label sizeToFit];
```

exactly before addSubview. And, there is was you problem, after font change

```
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0f] ;
```

so, you code must look like this:

```
float height = 0.0f;        
for (int i=0; i < answer_set.count; i++) {

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,height ,280,10 )];
    [label setText: [self.answer_set objectAtIndex:i]];
    [label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2941f green:0.4666f blue:0.9549f alpha:1.0f];
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    // [label sizeToFit]; // NOT HERE
    label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0f] ;
    [label sizeToFit]; // BUT HERE
    [self.percentage_ans_view addSubview:label];

    height += label.frame.size.height;
}
```